# Error in Svelte when removing data from a writable store that is reference by reactive variable

Tags: javascript, svelte, svelte-3

I'm running into an issue trying to delete an item from a store. I have a route `/view/:id` and am using that id to access a value from a custom writable store (`items`). I wrote a simple selector method to retrieve the item data based on the id, and have created a reactive `$: item` variable to listen for changes (items can be edited in this view). Here are the details from my `<script>`

```js
// ItemView.svelte
export let params: { id?: string } = {};
import { push } from "svelte-spa-router";
import { items } from "./stores/items";

$: [item] = items.select($items, params.id);

function handleDelete() {
  if (confirm("Are you sure you want to delete this item?")) {
    items.delete(item.id);
    push("/");
  }
}
```

When I call `handleDelete`, I get the following error:

```
Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: can't access property "type", ctx[0] is undefined
    update bundle.js:3796
    update index.mjs:764
    flush index.mjs:732
    promise callback*schedule_update index.mjs:707
    make_dirty index.mjs:1442
    ctx index.mjs:1477
    7 bundle.js:3898
    set index.mjs:35
    update index.mjs:43
    delete items.ts:59
    handleDelete ItemView.svelte:17
```

If I wrap `items.delete(item.id)` in a timeout, then everything works (5ms did the trick), but that doesn't seem right. I don't have a lot of experience with Svelte, but it feels like the issue is with the reactive variable unsubscribing. Should I be getting the single item data differently? Do I need to manually unsubscribe from the store before navigating?

I tried calling `unsubscribe` manually, but that didn't work either:

```js
export let params: { id?: string } = {};
import { push } from "svelte-spa-router";
import { items } from "./stores/items";
import { onDestroy } from "svelte";

let item;

const unsubscribe = items.subscribe(
  (value) => (item = items.select(value, params.id)[0])
);

function handleDelete() {
  if (confirm("Are you sure you want to delete this item?")) {
    unsubscribe(); // <- Here
    items.delete(item.id);
    push("/");
  }
}

onDestroy(unsubscribe);
```

That gave me the following error:

```
Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: stop is not a function
    subscribe index.mjs:58
    run index.mjs:18
    run_all index.mjs:24
    destroy_component index.mjs:1431
    update bundle.js:918
```

---

I'm not committed to any of the code I posted; I just want to be able to view a single item, and delete it and navigate away.

Comment: could you also post your store code ?

Comment: Maybe you are making it more complicated then necessary. Try this to get the item `$: item = $items.find(o => o.id == params.id);` and this to delete it `$items = $items.splice($items.findIndex(o => o.id == params.id), 1);`

Comment: @Molda That looks like it would work. My select function provides some additional ordering utilities that I would prefer not to lose.

Answer (score 2):

I learned that `ctx` in the error message referred to the right-hand side of the reactive variable assignment. In this instance, that was the return from my select method: `items.select($items, params.id)`.

`ctx[0]` is the first item in that array, or the variable that I created by destructuring: `$: [item]`.

So when Svelte said `ctx[0] is undefined`, it meant that there was no first entry in the `ctx` array; `item` was undefined (because it had been deleted).

I thought there was something important about the property "type", but it ended up just being the first key on `item` that I was trying to access in my markup: `{item.type}`. Trying to access any property would have failed.

By wrapping everything in an `{#if item}` condition, I was able to resolve the error:

```html
<!-- ItemView.svelte -->
{# if item}
<p>Type: {item.type}</p>
{/if}
```

I wouldn't recommend any of the above as a good pattern to follow. But if you are looking to resolve a similar issue, consider this solution.